# In Raspberry PI how can I achieve minimum write cycles to SD card and make RPI unplugged at any moment?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, filesystems, raspbian, sd-card

I am using raspberry PI for one of my project where it boots up from the micro SD card. 
The application records transactions in an c++ data structure and later stores to sql database inside microsd card. I can not loose that data as it is financial transaction.

Problem here is the backup power is available only for 30 secs.
I can detect the power failure event and initiate a shutdown. But I am not sure if it is going to be shutdown within 30 secs after writing the data safely to sql db.

I am also interested to minimize write cycles to micro SDcard.

I have seen internet routers use linux but can safely be unplugged at anytime. I think they use Overlays.

1. So is it possible to achieve similar file-system for raspberry pi?
2. Can I mount the SD card and then load the complete OS to memory and then run from there so that I am only worried to write down the data in sd card data partition but if it is not safely shutdown, my SD card root filesystem is not going to get corrupted ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's important information, is not possible to give it an internet connection to back it up? If internet is not possible, then you shouldn't be having the OS and important data on the same SD card. You don't know what type of crash might corrupt the data.

Solution:

Have two SD cards or two data storage units. Have the OS run on one, and when a transaction is being initiated, have the OS access the other SD card to execute the transaction. Only when the OS is done with the second SD card does it state that the transaction succeeded. The OS should not initiate a transaction if it detects power loss. I'm assuming no transaction will take anywhere close to 30 seconds (It should never take that long). If a transaction is occurring during power loss it should finish the transaction and then state that it succeeded, but refuse to take more entries. If 1 SD Card is truly necessary, then keep them in separate partitions but have the interactivity as described above.

Of course, this doesn't directly address shutdown. Now, Idk what's happening with your raspberry PI implementation, but shutting it down and writing to an SD Card should not take anywhere close to 30 seconds. If so, then there's another problem happening. Computers are very fast. "Minimizing SD card writes" is a very vague question, when we don't know what is being written.